# how to send data from one java program to another

Tags: java, web-services, sockets, rmi, rpc

We have a use case to:

1. start a java program from another java program.
2. Once the second java program is invoked, send a data-stream from the first java program to the second.

I checked that we can use sockets/rpc for it. I also saw that RMI/web-services are available and now confused with everything.

Could somebody point me to some good documentation about how to do this ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: can you describe a bit more?  Web content through a servlet is one such pattern, persistent storage in a file is another, socket data streams under some protocol may be another...

Comment: @Randy - we have data coming from our ETL framework that we get as flat files and we have to stream it to our first java program and then send it to second java program, which finally processes it.

Comment: You can also output the data from the first program to the input of the second, as usually done in *nix when concatenating command tools.

Comment: I forgot to mention that these 2 java programs are running on two different boxes. First one on AIX and second java program on another linux box. So, piping won't work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

RMI is going to be your simplest choice here (2 java programs running on the same box).  streaming data over rmi is not straightforward, however i've written the [RMIIO](http://openhms.sourceforge.net/rmiio/) library which makes that fairly easy.

Comment: I forgot to mention that these 2 java programs are running on two different boxes. First one on AIX and second java program on another linux box. So, piping won't work.

Comment: that's fine, nothing i said is changed by that.

Answer (score 0):

I've not come to use it myself, but I think [Terracotta](http://www.terracotta.org/) (more precisely the [distributed cache](http://www.terracotta.org/start/distributed-cache-tutorial)) may serve your needs (and provide much more).

Quoting from [Clojure + Terracotta = Yeah, Baby!](http://paul.stadig.name/2009/02/clojure-terracotta-yeah-baby.html) (emphasis is mine)

> Terracotta provides a network-attached, virtual, persistent heap and transparent inter-JVM thread coordination. With Terracotta, you no longer need to map your objects to database tables and back. You simply hand your object to Terracotta and it will cache your data. Not only does it cache your data, **but it will make your object available to a cluster of networked JVMs**.